# Improving Performance in RestApi hitting sharepoint folders

Tags: performance, sharepoint-online, rest

I am looking to fetch SP data using sharepoint Folder based Rest api. When i use filters, it is taking long time (close to one minute) to fetch the data. when i use pages rest api instead of folder level, that is faster. But my need is to hit the folder api. Any help would be appreciated.

Example:
this is faster  - https://sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/Lists/ **GetByTitle**('pages')/items?$ **select**=field1,field2,field3&$**orderby**=field5&$**filter**=field6&$**top**=10

This is slow  - https://sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/ **GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl**('pages/myfolder')/files?$**select**=ListItemAllFields/field1,ListItemAllFields/field2, ListItemAllFields/field3&$**orderby**=field5&$**filter**=ListItemAllFields/field6&$**top**=10

Do i need to change the way i am querying the folder to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint Online, you can use Microsoft Graph API for improved performance.

To get the files in the folder you can use below endpoint.

/me/drive/root:/path/to/folder:/children

I would suggest, you try your queries in [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

You can get further guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thanks Abhijeet. it helped. Though i cannot pull the items by folders with in the library. I can use drive/root/path/children. but it gives me the files and not file s with fields. Is there any way to pull list item @ folders under pages library and by using filters?